# EXCEL / VBA - Dynamically insert formulas into cells

Tags: excel, events, vba

I have a table and the number of rows it has is unknown. Every time the user enters an item into the column A of this table, I want the other columns in the table to dynamically get populated with formulas that reference the item just entered in column A.

I don't want to simply copy the formula into columns B,C,D etc all the way down my sheet because the number of rows in the sheet is unknown.

Is there any efficient way to do this?

My attempts of writing code in the onCalculate and onChange events in VBA seem very inefficient or result in eternal loops.

Comment: Got it....


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


    If Target.Column = 3 Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        
        Sheet2.Cells(Target.Row, 5).Formula = "=XXX(""XXX""," & Target.Address & " ,E5)"

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End If


End Sub

Comment: You can self answer if you'd like.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Excel 2007 or Excel 2010, defining your list range as a ***List*** will do that automatically !
*The best macro is no macro*

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample that will fill in the blank formulas in B,C and D whenever your selection changes:

In ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim oSh As Worksheet, oUsed As Range, oRng As Range

    Set oSh = Sh
    Set oUsed = oSh.UsedRange.Columns("B")

    'only add to blank formulas
    Set oRng = oUsed.Find("", LookIn:=xlFormulas)

    Do While Not oRng Is Nothing
        'B formula
        oRng.Offset(, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1] + 100"
        'C formula
        oRng.Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1] + 100"
        'D formula
        oRng.Offset(, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1] + 100"
        Set oRng = oUsed.Find("", oRng, xlFormulas)
    Loop
End Sub
```

This works on *every* worksheet in the workbook, so you may want to test which sheet you're in.

Comment: I would all to this something to check that the change happened in the correct column to speed up Excel.  Wrap your code in If Not Intersect(Target, oUsed) Is Nothing Then .... End If

Comment: @RonnieDickson - I thought of doing something like that, but Target only specifies what the Target cell is when you move from one cell to another.  So if I move from cell A1 to cell B25, Target's address is B25, and therefore it won't show up in the intersect... not sure how else to check for changes only in the A column. Another way to speed it up would be to disable screen updating, but this might be overkill.